# There exists a unique homomorphism $h \colon K' \rightarrow K$ such that $i = i_k h$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, ring-homomorphism

> Let $f \colon M \rightarrow N$ be a homomorphism, $K = \ker f$ and $i_k \colon K \rightarrow M$ the inclusion homomorphism.
>
> If $i \colon K' \rightarrow M$ is a monomorphism such that $f i = 0$, then there exists a unique homomorphism $h \colon K' \rightarrow K$ such that $i = i_k h$.

My try:

If $f i = 0$, then $i(K') \subset K$, and then I define $h \colon K' \rightarrow K$ such that $h(k') = i(k')$.
Then
$$
  (i_k h)(k) = i_k(h(k)) = i_k(i(k)) = i(k) \,.
$$

Is this right?

Comment: What are $M$ and $N$? Modules?

Comment: @AlexMathers Yes! R-Mods

Comment: Your proof of existence is correct and uniqueness is easy. I find the formulation of this "theorem" overcomplcated for such a trivial situation.

Comment: @AnneBauval the uniqueness its because $i_k$ monomorphism too right?

Comment: Yes. In fact all this stuff can be reformulated in terms of inclusions.